# Bash Script how to use sed to replace text after a number?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, cut

```
{"success":true,"message":"","result":[{"Id":66719299,"TimeStamp":"2017-08-29T16:35:35.937","Quantity":0.80122000,"Price":0.01379000,"Total":0.01104882,"FillType":"PARTIAL_FILL","OrderType":"SELL"},{"Id":66719283,"TimeStamp":"2017-08-29T16:35:32.36","Quantity":7.36427025,"Price":0.01379000,"Total":0.10155328,"FillType":"PARTIAL_FILL","OrderType":"SELL"},{"Id":66719222,"TimeStamp":"2017-08-29T16:35:13.263","Quantity":24.03098850,"Price":0.01379000,"Total":0.33138733,"FillType":"PARTIAL_FILL","OrderType":"SELL"},{"Id":66719221,"TimeStamp":"2017-08-29T16:35:13.013","Quantity":0.70000000,"Price":0.01379000,"Total":0.00965300,"FillType":"PARTIAL_FILL","OrderType":"SELL"},{"Id":66719220,"TimeStamp":"2017-08-29T16:35:12.623","Quantity":31.30579055,"Price":0.01379000,"Total":0.43170685,"FillType":"PARTIAL_FILL","OrderType":"BUY"},{"Id":66719219,"TimeStamp":"2017-08-29T16:35:12.623","Quantity":12.87144703,"Price":0.01378000,"Total":0.17736854,"FillType":"PARTIAL_FILL","OrderType":"BUY"}]}
```

Im stuck on how I would use sed to remove anything after 66719222 including and then adding ]} at the end. The output should be

This is what I want to delete:

```
,{"Id":66719222,"TimeStamp":"2017-08-29T16:35:13.263","Quantity":24.03098850,"Price":0.01379000,"Total":0.33138733,"FillType":"PARTIAL_FILL","OrderType":"SELL"},{"Id":66719221,"TimeStamp":"2017-08-29T16:35:13.013","Quantity":0.70000000,"Price":0.01379000,"Total":0.00965300,"FillType":"PARTIAL_FILL","OrderType":"SELL"},{"Id":66719220,"TimeStamp":"2017-08-29T16:35:12.623","Quantity":31.30579055,"Price":0.01379000,"Total":0.43170685,"FillType":"PARTIAL_FILL","OrderType":"BUY"},{"Id":66719219,"TimeStamp":"2017-08-29T16:35:12.623","Quantity":12.87144703,"Price":0.01378000,"Total":0.17736854,"FillType":"PARTIAL_FILL","OrderType":"BUY"}]}
```

and replace it with `]}`

so the output is

```
{"success":true,"message":"","result":[{"Id":66719299,"TimeStamp":"2017-08-29T16:35:35.937","Quantity":0.80122000,"Price":0.01379000,"Total":0.01104882,"FillType":"PARTIAL_FILL","OrderType":"SELL"},{"Id":66719283,"TimeStamp":"2017-08-29T16:35:32.36","Quantity":7.36427025,"Price":0.01379000,"Total":0.10155328,"FillType":"PARTIAL_FILL","OrderType":"SELL"}]}
```

Thanks if anyone could help.

Comment: If you have to use `sed` rather than a tool that properly understands your text's format, try: `sed 's/},{.*/]}/'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/,{"Id":66719222.*/]}/' filename
```

Or if you're willing to sacrifice clarity to make the command one character shorter:

```
sed 's/,[^}]*66719222.*/]}/' filename
```

Or more crudely:

```
sed 's/.\{7\}66719222.*/]}/' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `file` is your filename.

```
sed 's/\(.*\),{"Id":66719222.*/\1\]}/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is in bash, why not just use bash:

```
str='{"success":true,"message":"","result":[{"Id":66719299,"TimeStamp":"2017-08-29T16:35:35.937","Quantity":0.80122000,"Price":0.01379000,"Total":0.01104882,"FillType":"PARTIAL_FILL","OrderType":"SELL"},{"Id":66719283,"TimeStamp":"2017-08-29T16:35:32.36","Quantity":7.36427025,"Price":0.01379000,"Total":0.10155328,"FillType":"PARTIAL_FILL","OrderType":"SELL"},{"Id":66719222,"TimeStamp":"2017-08-29T16:35:13.263","Quantity":24.03098850,"Price":0.01379000,"Total":0.33138733,"FillType":"PARTIAL_FILL","OrderType":"SELL"},{"Id":66719221,"TimeStamp":"2017-08-29T16:35:13.013","Quantity":0.70000000,"Price":0.01379000,"Total":0.00965300,"FillType":"PARTIAL_FILL","OrderType":"SELL"},{"Id":66719220,"TimeStamp":"2017-08-29T16:35:12.623","Quantity":31.30579055,"Price":0.01379000,"Total":0.43170685,"FillType":"PARTIAL_FILL","OrderType":"BUY"},{"Id":66719219,"TimeStamp":"2017-08-29T16:35:12.623","Quantity":12.87144703,"Price":0.01378000,"Total":0.17736854,"FillType":"PARTIAL_FILL","OrderType":"BUY"}]}'

echo "${x%66719222*}66719222]}"
```